# finding the polar set

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

the question say find the polar-duals of the following sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$

1) $\{(x,y):x\geq 2\}$

2) $\{(x,y):x\leq 2\}$

3) $\{(x,y):x=2\}$

the answers are $\{(x,0):x\leq 0\}$
, $\{(x,0):0\leq x\leq 1/2\}$
, $\{(x,0):x\leq 1/2\}$
 why y cannot take any value other than zero??

also i don't know how to take any step in showing that the polar set of $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1, x \leq 0\}\cup \{(x,y):0\leq x\leq 1, |y|\leq 1\}$
is $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1, x\leq 0\} \cup \{(x,y):|y|\leq 1-x, x\geq 0\}$.

Comment: the polar set of {(x,y):x^2+y^2$\leqq$1,x $\leqq$ 0} is {(x,y):x^2+y^2$\leqq$,x$\leqq$0}
and the polar set of {(x,y):0$\leqq$x$\leqq$1,|y|$\leqq$1} is {(x,y):|y|$\leqq$1-x,x$\leqq$0}
and it is easily seen that the polar of (A $\cup$ B) is the polar   of A$ \cap$ the polar of B
which results that the polar of {(x,y):$x^2$+$y^2$ $\leqq$ 1,x$\leqq$ 0} $\cup$ {(x,y):0$\leqq$ x $\leqq$ 1, |y| $\leqq$ 1} is the empty set !!!!!!
HOW!!??

Comment: @TeXminator ???

Comment: That's because your assumption is wrong. The "left" half of the Euclidean unit disk is *not* equal to its polar set. For example, you can easily check that the polar contains all points $(x,0)$ with non-negative $x$. The other polar set seems to be wrong as well.

Comment: i proved that the polar of {(x,y):0<=x<=1,|y|<=1} is {(x,y):|y|<=1-x,x>=0}.
and you are right with the polar of the left half of the euclidean unit disk .
But what do you think about?what is the polar of the left half of the euclidean unit ball??

Comment: i think the polar of left euclidean unit ball is all the unit  ball

Comment: The polar of the left half of the Euclidean unit ball is the union of itself and the strip $[0,\infty)\times [-1,1]$. Try to use GeoGebra to get better initial guesses of your polar sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polar of a set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined as

$$
A^\circ = \{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2: \sup_{(x,y)\in A} (ax+by) \leq 1\}.
$$

Let $(a,b)\in A^\circ$, where $A=\{(x,y):x R 2\}$, and $R$ denotes one of the relations $\geq$, $\leq$, $=$. Assume that $b>0$. For a sequence of points $(x,y_i)\in A$ with fixed $xR2$ and $y_i\to +\infty$, we obtain
$$
1\geq \sup_{(x^\prime,y^\prime)\in A}(ax^\prime+by^\prime)\geq \sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}(ax+by_i)=\infty,
$$
a contradiction. Similarly for $b<0$, where you take $y_i\to -\infty$. This answers the first question.

The answer to your second question is rather obvious if you have in mind that the dual norm of the Euclidean norm is the Euclidean norm, and that the taxicab norm is the dual norm of the maximum norm (and vice versa). Note that you have a pair of dual norms, the unit balls are the polar sets of each other.

**EDIT:** More precisely, let $$A=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1, x \leq 0\}\cup \{(x,y):0\leq x\leq 1, |y|\leq 1\}$$
and $$B=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1, x\leq 0\} \cup \{(x,y):|y|\leq 1-x, x\geq 0\}.$$

In order to show that $B$ is the polar set of $A$, we have to show that $ax+by\leq 1$ whenever $(x,y)\in A$ and $(a,b)\in B$. We do this via a case distinction. Let $\|\cdot\|$ denote the Euclidean norm.

Case 1. $x^2+y^2\leq 1$, $x\leq 0$

Case 1.1. $a^2+b^2\leq 1$, $a\leq 0$. The Cauchy--Schwarz inequality yields $ax+by\leq \|(x,y)|\|\|(a,b)\|\leq 1\cdot 1=1$.

Case 1.2. $|b|\leq 1-a$, $a\geq 0$. Then $\|(a,b)\|\leq 1$ and, again, Cauchy--Schwarz yields $ax+by\leq \|(x,y)|\|\|(a,b)\|\leq 1\cdot 1=1$.

Case 2: $0\leq x\leq 1, |y|\leq 1$

Case 2.2. $|b|\leq 1-a$, $a\geq 0$. The Hölder inequality yields $|ax|+|by|=ax+by\leq \|(x,y)\|_\infty \|(a,b)\|_1 \leq 1\cdot 1\leq 1$. Here, $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is the maximum norm and $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the taxicab norm. Note that you have $|ax|+|by|=ax+by$ since all four numbers are non-negative.

Case 2.1. $a^2+b^2\leq 1$, $a\leq 0$. We have $ax+by=\|(x,y)\|\|(a,b)\|\cos\alpha\leq\|(x,y)\|\cos\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the angle between $(x,y)$ and $(a,b)$. What is an upper bound for $\|(x,y)\|\cos\alpha$? For fixed $(x,y)$ in the right half of $A$ and variable $(a,b)$ in the left half of $B$ we can maximize this expression by reducing the angle $\alpha$. That is, the maximum will be attained at $(a,b)=(0,1)$ if $(x,y)$ lies in the upper half-plane and at $(a,b)=(0,-1)$ if $(x,y)$ lies in the lower half-plane. By symmetry, we can restrict ourselves to the upper half-plane for a worst-case analysis. First observation: Let $(x^\prime,y^\prime)$ be the intersection point of the boundary of $A$ and the ray starting at $(0,0)$ passing through $(x,y)$. Then $(x^\prime,y^\prime)=\lambda(x,y)$ with $\lambda \geq 1$. Therefore, $0 x^\prime+1y^\prime=y^\prime\geq y=0x^\prime+1y^\prime$. In other words: Without loss of generality, $(x,y)$ is a boundary point of $A$. If $(x,y)$ lies in the line segment between $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$, then the three points $(x,y)=(x,1)$, $(0,1)$, and $(0,0)$ are the vertices of a right triangle and $\|(x,y)\|\cos\alpha =\|(0,1)\|=1$. (See the trigonometric definition of the cosine function in right triangles.) If $(x,y)$ lies in the line segment between $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$, then $45^\circ\leq \alpha\leq 90^\circ$ and $\|(x,y)\|=\|(y,x)\|$ but $$\cos(\alpha)=\sin(90^\circ-\alpha)\leq \cos(90^\circ-\alpha).$$ (Note that $90^\circ-\alpha$ is the angle between $(y,x)$ and $(0,1)$.) Therefore $\|(x,y)\|\cos(\alpha)\leq 1$.

This completes the first step of the proof. We showed that $ax+by\leq 1$ whenever $(x,y)\in A$ and $(a,b)\in B$, that is, $B\subset A^\circ$ and $A\subset B^\circ$. The definition of the polar set shows that $A\subset B^\circ$ is equivalent to $A^\circ\supset (B^\circ)^\circ =B$, where the latter equality is a consequence of $B$ being a closed convex set containing the origin.

Would've been much easier if I had used convex analytic and geometric ideas.

**EDIT 2:** Now here is the geometric truth: Fix a point $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Find the closed half-plane $H(x,y)$ with the following properties:

1) Its bounding line is orthogonal to the line through $(0,0)$ and $(x,y)$.

2) The orthogonal distance between $(0,0)$ and the bounding line is $\|(x,y)\|^{-1}$.

3) $(0,0)\in H(x,y)$.

Then $H(x,y)$ is actually the polar set of $\{(x,y)\}$. (That should be easy to check.) The polar set of $A$ is then the intersection of all half-spaces $H(x,y)$ where $(x,y)$ runs through $A$:
\begin{align*}
A^\circ&=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2: ax+by\leq 1 \;\forall\; (x,y)\in A\}\\
&=\bigcap_{(x,y)\in A}\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2: ax+by\leq 1\}\\
&=\bigcap_{(x,y)\in A}H(x,y)
\end{align*}
In particular, if $(x,y)$ runs through the boundary of $A$, then $H(x,y)$ run through the supporting half-spaces of $A^\circ$. (Those a closed half-spaces which contain $A^\circ$ but the corresponding open half-plane does not.)

The convex analytic truth is as follows. Instead of $A$, you take the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ which coincides with the Euclidean norm in the left half-plane, and with the maximum norm in the right half-plane. (It's called the Minkowski functional of $A$.) When $f$ is differentiable, then the gradient is a point of the boundary of $A^\circ$. In the left half-plane, $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, which is differentiable with gradient $\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}(x,y)}$. In the right half-plane, $f(x,y)=y$ for $y>x$, $f(x,y)=-y$ for $y<-x$, and $f(x,y)=x$ for $-x<y<x$. The respective gradients are $\color{red}{(0,1)}$, $\color{red}{(0,-1)}$, $\color{red}{(1,0)}$. Indeed, the red points are boundary points of $B$ which is our candidate for $A^\circ$. With this approach, you leave out the line segments between $(0,\pm 1)$ and $(1,0)$ because $f$ is not differentiable when $y=\pm x$. (In fact, it is subdifferentiable there and the left out line segments are the subgradients of $f$ on $y=\pm x$.) But that is not a serious problem because from the geometric truth we know that $A^\circ$ is a closed convex set.

Comment: but how if we asume that b>0 then for any sequence of points (x,$y_i$) $\in$ A with $y_i$ $\longrightarrow$ + $\infty$,we obtain $\sup(ax+by)$ on (x,y) $\in$ A >= $\sup$(ax+b$y_i$)on i $\in$ N,thanks

Comment: That is because $(x,y_i)\in A$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore $\{ax+by_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset \{ax^\prime+by^\prime:(x^\prime,y^\prime)\in A\}$ for fixed $xR2$.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify that $x$ is fixed in $\sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}(ax+by_i)$, but it is not in $\sup_{(x,y)\in A}(ax+by)$. So I added \prime there.

Comment: ok,Thanks .
but in Q2  how i have a pair of dual norms

Comment: In your second question, the parts of the sets in the left half-plane are the part of the Euclidean unit ball in the left half-plane. For the right half-plane, you have half of the square $[-1,1]^2$, which is the unit ball of the maximum norm, and half of the rotated square which is the unit ball of the taxicab norm. If you want, I can try to edit my answer and provide some explicit calculations, if this helps. If you are just fine with geometric intuition, I can provide that, too.

Comment: Thanks very munch ,but if you can provide geometric intuition ,i want it ,please

Comment: See the second edit of my answer.

Comment: Thank you very very much :)

Comment: I enjoy explaining the Hahn--Banach theorem :-)

Comment: To show that the polar of  A={(a,b):0 $\leqq$a$\leqq$1, |b|$\leqq$ 1}
is {(x,y):|y|$\leqq$ 1-x, x$\geqq$ 0}.
For each point (x,y) of A*,define a point (a,b) of A by the conditions that b=1 if y $\geqq$ 0 , b=-1 if y <0 and a =1 if x >=0 then (a,b).(x,y)=ax+by=x+|y|<=1
Conversely,suppose that (x,y) satisfies  x>=0,x+|y|<=1.Then for any point (a,b) of A ,ax+by<=x+|b||y|<=x+|y|<=1.
Since 0<=a<=1,x>=0.